# Please help me fix this crash on Windows XP and any version of IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, watin

I am using WATIN 2.1 with C#. Here is my Code

```
// Should I add something here like []
private void ProcessInkPresenter()
{
    String path = "http://localhost/index.asp?HOSTID=AD&USERID=&ALIAS=" + userName;
    Int32 startingRow = 1;
    using (var browser = new IE(path))
    {
        browser.AutoClose = true;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                browser.Image(Find.ByAlt("Use a password")).Click();
                browser.WaitForComplete(90);
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("_MYPW")).TypeText(privateCurrentPassword);

                // the application keeps crashing in the line above
                // WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException : RunScript failed
                //      ----> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

                browser.Image(Find.ByAlt("Verify password")).Click();
                browser.Link(Find.ByTitle("Change passwords")).Click();
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("_NEWP1")).TypeText(privateNewPassword);
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("_NEWP2")).TypeText(privateNewPassword);
                browser.Image(Find.ByName("SUBMIT-CHANGE")).Click();
```

I basically need to get this to work with Internet Explorer 7 and up on Windows XP.
Can you please help me with this?

I added the CRASH details in the code above

Thanks

Comment: There's a question in here somewhere... I'm sure of it!

Comment: Please add more information and a question rather than "Can you please help me with this"

Comment: The issue is that its crashing. I added the crash details in the comments in the code above. I am using WATIN 2.1 on Windows XP. I tested it with IE 6, 7, 8 and all have the same exact crash. I think it has to do with TypeText but I don't know a workaround

Comment: The browser is busy so it cannot handle the type text method. The "browser.WaitForComplete(90)" 90 sec timeout is not enough.

Comment: I've tried other values instead of 90's like 4000.

Comment: For some reason the browser is busy(loading) and watin failing to communicate with him. Try to debug it stop on click perform the click refresh the browser manually and run the typetext.

Comment: The browser gives no indication that it is busy. It appears that the form is finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the field found?

```
var field = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("_MYPW"));
if(field.Exists)
    field.TypeText(privateCurrentPassword);
```

I had a similar issue [trying to get an HTML5 input type email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024178/watin-support-for-html5-tags/10044881#10044881).
It could also be other reasons watin can't get to the field.

Comment: Yes that is the issue. I wish our company used HTML5 but it's poorly designed HTML 4.x. Did you find a work around?