# WatiN support for HTML5 tags

Tags: watin

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="email" id="email">
```

I want to type text into it from WatiN :

```
var field = Browser.TextField("email");
Assert.IsTrue(field.Exists);
```

But the field can't be found. This is because WatiN doesn't support HTML5 tags yet.
I found a [solution](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=watin-users&max_rows=100&style=nested&viewmonth=201204) to this by creating an extended TextField-class:

```
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "text", Index = 0)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "password", Index = 1)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "textarea", Index = 2)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "hidden", Index = 3)]
[ElementTag("textarea", Index = 4)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "email", Index = 5)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "url", Index = 6)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "number", Index = 7)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "range", Index = 8)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "search", Index = 9)]
[ElementTag("input", InputType = "color", Index = 10)] 
public class TextFieldExtended : TextField
{
    public TextFieldExtended(DomContainer domContainer, INativeElement element)
        : base(domContainer, element)
    {
    }

    public TextFieldExtended(DomContainer domContainer, ElementFinder finder)
        : base(domContainer, finder)
    {
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        Type typeToRegister = typeof (TextFieldExtended);
        ElementFactory.RegisterElementType(typeToRegister);
    }
}
```

After registering the type and running the code it still doesn't work. Can anyone see why or does anyone have another workaround for this problem?

Comment: Thanks - works great - you ommitted one attribute:     [ElementTag("input", InputType = "tel", Index = 11)]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var field = Browser.TextField("email");
```

Tries to get the TextField with id email and thus fails for the TextFieldExtended type.

```
var field = Browser.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>("email");
```

Gets the TextFieldExtended with id email.

Comment: If anyone else didn't have access to `TextFieldExtend`: https://github.com/sergiomokshin/DiarioEscolar/blob/master/DiarioEscolar.AcceptanceTests/StepHelpers/TextFieldExtended.cs