# How to login on blogger with watin?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, watin

This is my watin code:

**EDIT:**

```
            ie.GoTo("http://blogger.com");
            ie.WaitForComplete();
            ie.TextField("Email").TypeText("test");
            ie.TextField("Passwd").TypeText("test");
            ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Sign in")).Click();
```

It's not typing the "test" into the email field.

I am using IE 9.

**Exception that I get:** Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'id' equals 'Email' at https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=blogger&passive=1209600&continue=http://www.blogger.com/home&followup=http://www.blogger.com/home&ltmpl=start#s01

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't see why it's downvoted ...

Comment: What does `without success` mean? It finds the element but doesn't put any text in it? Does it throw any exceptions? Does it fail silently? What version of IE? The lack of information may be the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @Arran thanks, I've just edited the post.

Comment: I think the problem is the type of the field. The exception tells that it couldn't find input (hidden, password, text or textarea), but the type of the field is "email". How can I tell him that the type is "email" ?

Comment: The `email` type for input elements is HTML5 only. Watin doesn't support HTML5. May be a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024178/watin-support-for-html5-tags  ...or type into the element using Javascript directly.

Comment: I tried that now, but it I get an error for INativeElement, seems like I am missing an assembly..

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  It cannot find the field with the id `Email` you sure thats the correct id?

Comment: Ramhound yes, it's 100% it's email, lol
@CodeCaster I mentioned from the first time what I've tried.

Comment: _"I tried lot of things to put some text in the email field, but without success."_ - this was (and still is) your problem description. Do you find that useful to anyone who does not know what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as laid out in this answer.
[WatiN support for HTML5 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024178/watin-support-for-html5-tags)

If not already *using* `WatiN.Core.Native` you'll need to add that to your *using* directives, or modify the TextFieldExtended method declaration to have the full object path:  WatiN.Core.Native.INativeElement

```
browser.GoTo("http://www.blogger.com");
browser.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>("Email").TypeText("me@you.com");
```

Works like a champ.  Only checked on Watin2.1 - IE9 - Win7