# watin not working with live.com

Tags: c#, .net, watin

I am trying to use watin to mimic login to live.com using c#. code is below.

```
IE myIE = new IE("http://login.live.com/");  
myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("login")).TypeText("abc@abc.com"); 
myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("passwd")).TypeText("1234"); 

myIE.Button(Find.ByValue("Sign in")).Click();
```

However it always failed to find the textfield:

> WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'login' at `http://login.live.com/`

The sample code in home page of `http://watin.org/` works fine for `www.google.com`.

Did I miss something or is there anything special on `http://login.live.com` that prevents watin to work?

PS: I am running windows 7 64bit. VS 2008 with .net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting issues because the email field you're trying to type in is an HTML5 element.

Create the TextFieldExtended class as defined in this SO question:  [WatiN support for HTML5 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024178/watin-support-for-html5-tags)

Then your code will be like the below:

```
ie.GoTo("http://login.live.com/");
ie.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>(Find.ByName("login")).TypeText("thisismyusername@here.com");
ie.TextField(Find.ByName("passwd")).TypeText("thisismypassword");
ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Sign in")).Click();
```

Tested on Watin2.1, IE9, Win7-64.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thanks! Watin should add this features in as html5 getting popular.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this: I got it to work on my end:

```
ie.Div(Find.ByCustom("innertext","someone@example.com")).Click();
ie.TextField(Find.ById("i0116")).TypeText("hello");
ie.TextField(Find.ById("i0118")).Click();
ie.TextField(Find.ById("i0118")).TypeText("Hello!");
```

I recommend using this test Recorder. It will give you the elemnt names to use in your source:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19180/WatiN-Test-Recorder

Edit:

I was also able to get this to work when finding by divID.

```
ie.Element(Find.ById("idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample")).Click()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. the first line doesn't work since it can't find the TextField at all. The test recorder(http://sourceforge.net/projects/watintestrecord/?source=dlp) seems outdated, it won't run in windows 7.

Comment: Also, the ID's may be dynamic, i haven't checked. You may need to use regex.

Comment: I can't find ByCustom method, which version of Watin do you use? ie.Element(Find.ById("idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample")).Click() can compile. However after adding this line before find textfield,  I am still getting same exception. Would you be able to send your project to tinhutyAThotmailDOTcom. thanks!