# Access ASP:Text Value with Watin

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, watin

I've only started working with watin a few days ago and I'm having a slight problem. I am writing a very simple test to change the text of `UserName`. The code is:

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" autocomplete="off" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Username field is required." />
</div>
```

And my Test code is:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (var browser = new IE("My Url"))
        {
            browser.TextField(Find.ByName("UserName")).TypeText("some text");
        }
    }
}
```

When ever I run the test I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'UserName' at about:blank

I've come across **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024178/watin-support-for-html5-tags)** question but still get the same error. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance for all your help and support.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML source in the browser? The IDs of HTML tags often depend on the containing elements in the ASP file, so the name or Id of the text box might not just be `UserName`.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the HTML code for that `<asp:TextBox />` element in your design file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find.ById` instead of `Find.ByName`:

```
browser.TextField(Find.ById("UserName")).TypeText("some text");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it's giving exactly the same error

Comment: Can you check in the source what is the id of the textbox ?

Comment: I've just checked the id and it's `MainContent_UserName` I've changed it in my code but still getting the same error :/

Comment: Then try adding a Name property to the texbox and using Find.ByName.

Comment: Textbox server control doesn't have the name property or am I missing something?